# Should I write tests for code that is called by other tested code

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, bdd

if I have two classes:  ClassA and ClassB.

ClassA calls a public method on ClassB i.e. in ClassA:

```
public function foo()
{
    $this->classB->bar();
}
```

I have tests covering foo - but should I always write tests covering also bar in class b?

Given that the code is tested in directly im not sure if this is worthwhile or not?

Comment: On a related note, also see the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should test also bar. All your classes should have their own test case, where you test their public methods. Therefore you should have a separate test case for classB, where you test method bar().

The reason for this is that when an error occures in method bar() (or in another method of classB which bar() calls), your test will fail at method foo(), which can be confising and cause more time to find the actual error in method bar(). It may not seen to be a problem in your example, but in the real world, you test more complex code.

Another reason is the test complexity. Your tests should test your methods in all possible cases. Lets say, function bar() can be tested in 5 different cases, and also foo() can be tested in its own 5 cases. In case you would be testing only foo(), you would have to write a test to cover 5*5 = 25 cases. And if foo() were more complex, and called another method, lets say classB->bar2() with another 5 different cases, you would have to write a test that covers 5*5*5 = 125 cases! It is a lot easier to write 3 tests, echach for 5 cases, than 1 test to cover 125 cases. And those 3 tests would also be easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

The other way to look at it is in terms of the responsibility of the class.
That responsibility is what should be Asserted with tests.

Class can be ClassA or ClassB etc
Write Tests to assert responsibilities of Class A
Write Tests to assert responsibilities of Class B

Combine that with the view that there will a dependencies and object maps
You l naturally cover tests for your dependencies and then higher up the object map tracing to the root

In short
Class B needs to have tests
Class A which depends on some capability of Class B needs tests of its own

Note: the responsibility/capability of each of them will be different

Answer (score 0):

Yes, write the test. Otherwise, classB::bar() is not reusable (or even usable.)

If bar were a private method of ClassA, you wouldn't have to.